# Single column fetch returning in list in python postgresql

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, list

Database:

| id | trade | token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 5523 |
| 2 | fdfd | 5145 |
| 3 | sdfd | 2899 |

Code:

```
def db_fetchquery(sql):
    conn    = psycopg2.connect(database="trade", user='postgres', password='jps', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row = cursor.rowcount
    if row >= 1:
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return data
    conn.close()
    return False

print(db_fetchquery("SELECT token FROM script"))
```

Result:

> [(5523,),(5145,),(2899,)]

But I need results as:

> [5523,5145,2899]

I also tried `print(db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script")[0])` but this gave result as:- [(5523,)]

Also, why is there ',' / list inside list when I am fetching only one column?

Comment: The `,` is a way Python core developers found to disambiguate a tuple with one element and an expression. So in your case, for instance, `(5523,)` is a tuple with a single element, `5523`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if you are able to do that without further processing but I would do it like this:

```
data = [x[0] for x in data]
```

which convert the list of tuples to a 1D list